# Issue in scaling html on mobile and desktop browser

Tags: css, html

I have an html like this

```
    <div class="movies">
  <ul>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
    <li class="item"></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

and css like this

```
.movies {
   overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   border: 5px solid #8;
   white-space: nowrap;
   margin-top:5px;
```

}

```
.item {
background-color:#eee;
border: 5px solid #888;
border-radius:3px;
height: 200px;
width: 30%;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden; 
margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Because I used width:30%; it works fine for on iPhone and other small devices but for desktop browsers 30% of the whole screen width becomes too large. how can I scale the list appropriately for all platforms?

Comment: how about [media queries?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: yes I can use that but then I have to specify the width of all mobile devices and change each of the style sheets accordingly?

Comment: That, or setting max-widths to everything

Answer (score 0):

**You have to target screen size using media query for different secreen size ...
for iphone**

@media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 375px) 
    and (max-device-width : 667px) 
    and (orientation : landscape) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
{ }

@media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 375px) 
    and (max-device-width : 667px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
{

}

**and for desktop version..**

@media only screen (max-width: 1080){

}